# PostgreSQL/RedShift - students that attended zero classes on a given day

Tags: postgresql

I have a couple of tables:

students

```
id,name,email,age
01,john,john@something.com,14
02,Mike,mike@something.com,15
03,Ted,Ted@something.com,14
```

Classes

```
classid,classname,date,studentid
01,Mathematics,2017-01-01,01
02,Physics,2017-01-01,01
03,Physics,2017-01-01,02
04,Chemsitry,2017-01-01,01
```

`students.id = classes.studentid`. Note that Ted has not attended any class on 2017-01-01. How do I find students that have zero classes on a given day? I am looking for an output like this:

```
name,email,date,class
Ted,ted@something.com,2017-01-01,NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT <fields> FROM students LEFT OUTER JOIN class ON classes.studentid =  students.id WHERE classes.id IS NULL` - the outer join will output one row per student for each matching class *and one row per student with no matching classes*, checking for classes.id being NULL will bring out just the output where there was no match.

Lookup how `OUTER JOIN`s work and how they differ from `INNER JOIN`s (note that by default if you don't specify otherwise joins are `INNER`) for more detail.

As a side note your model does appear to be in normal form: I would expect to have a table for students, a table for classes, and a table for the relationships between the two - your `classes` tbale appears to mix the latter two which may lead to consistency problems later.

Comment: Thanks David. I did try left outer join and the output didn't seem correct (I may be wrong, will try again). The data comes from a NOSQL database, so its a bit weird.